# Decrease Woocommerce Storefront theme footer height

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, height, storefront

I'm having really hard time trying to change my footer height. Actual footer is way to big and tall. I'd need to reduce it as much as possible. I tried to search for the style.css file but can't find it and I'm not sure if that's where the code belongs, please!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following where you can adjust values *(to be added in the styles.css file of your active theme)*:

```css
.site-footer {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0.7em !important;
}
.site-info {
    padding: 0.5em 0 !important;
}
```

It should quiet reduce footer height decreasing the padding top and padding bottom of footer container and some other child container…

Before and after:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank u!!! the style.css in the storefront theme or in the child storefront theme? @LoicTheAztec not so sure about where that file is.

Comment: @AuraServants The child, if you are using that